# Creating a toggle button for script call

Tags: javascript

I have the following glitch effect applied to a section of my page, however it can be quite distracting. I wish to create a toggle button to disable and re-enable the script.

http://eg-graphics.com/zwooper/EGVGV/Season3/MemoryWall.html

So to call the function I have the following code:

```
 $( function() {
    $( ".glitch-img" ).mgGlitch({
        destroy : false, // set 'true' to stop the plugin
        glitch: true, // set 'false' to stop glitching
        scale: true, // set 'false' to stop scaling
        blend : true, // set 'false' to stop glitch blending
        blendModeType : 'hue', // select blend mode type
        glitch1TimeMin : 600, // set min time for glitch 1 elem
        glitch1TimeMax : 900, // set max time for glitch 1 elem
        glitch2TimeMin : 10, // set min time for glitch 2 elem
        glitch2TimeMax : 115, // set max time for glitch 2 elem
    });
});
```

To disable this plugin i need to set it so it's `destroy : true.`

Where I struggle is that I am unable to recall the function with `destroy:true` and then again with `destroy : false`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var toggle=false; 
$("#toggleBut").on("click",function() { 
    toggle=!toggle; 
    $( ".glitch-img" ).mgGlitch({destroy : toggle }); 
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvMMzw

Comment: Maybe better `$("#toggleBut").on("click",function() { $( ".glitch-img" ).mgGlitch({destroy : $('.glitch-img .front-1').length > 0 }); });` ?

Comment: @mplungjan 's suggestion was clear in my opinion. Thank you though!